# WKWebView issue app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

I have a controller and I want to instantiate a WKWebView programmatically.
For this reason I add a container view by storyboard and by code I want to add a WKWebView inside it.
This is the code:

```
#import "testController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

    @interface testController()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;

    @end

    @implementation testController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.webView = [[WKWebView new] initWithFrame:self.container.frame];
        self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
        self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.container.frame.size.width, self.container.frame.size.height);
        [self.container addSubview:self.webView];


        [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"testString "baseURL:nil];

    }

    @end
```

This code works but not always and sometimes it crashes and I get this error in the terminal log:

```
-[__NSCFString _webView:renderingProgressDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000838ce0
2018-05-25 16:04:26.001917+0200 AppTest iOS[4853:171971] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString _webView:renderingProgressDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000838ce0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

But I don't able to understand why.

EDIT 1:
This controller is inside a navigation controller and I notice that if I put in a navigation controller I get this error (sometimes), while I remove it from navigation controller everything work fine

Comment: This is not relevant to what you asked, but this code is wrong: `initWithFrame:self.container.frame`. You mean `self.container.bounds`. You could then eliminate the line later where you "fix" the problem by setting the `frame` all over again.

Comment: [WKWebView new] is short for [[WKWebView alloc] init] so technically you are initializing the instance twice.  That usually doesn't cause crashes though.  Secondly, -initWithFrame:configuration: is the designated initializer, so try using that instead.  Somehow an NSString is getting installed as an internal, private delegate (or, possibly, the double init may be causing the delegate instance to be deallocated but still referenced, and an NSString gets allocated in its old memory position, causing these types of crashes).  Maybe change +new to +alloc and see what happens.