# WKWebview Crash frequently

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

```
   WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    config.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    config.preferences.javaScriptEnabled=true;
    config.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = YES;
   
    //Create new UIWebView for launched-app
    
    WKWebView *appWebView = [[WKWebView new] initWithFrame:portalSizes configuration:config];
    appWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    appWebView.UIDelegate=self;
    appWebView.allowsLinkPreview=false;
    appWebView.tag = WebView_Tag + launchedApps.count;
    [appWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(appSize.width * launchedApps.count, 0, appSize.width, appSize.height)];
    [appWebView setNavigationDelegate:self];
     
    //[appWebView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    appWebView.scrollView.tag = ScrollView_Tag + launchedApps.count;
    appWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [appWebView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM _webView:renderingProgressDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28254cab0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Please share some code how you instantiate WKWebView and the content you try to load. Otherwise this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531050/wkwebview-issue-app-crash

Comment: Updated the require information

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation of variable `appWebView` is incorrect. `[WKWebView new]` is shortcut for `[[WKWebView alloc] init]` so your are potentially initialising the control twice.

Replace `[[WKWebView new] initWithFrame:portalSizes configuration:config]`
with `[[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:portalSizes configuration:config]` and check if this helps to prevent your code from crashing.

(Also using the tag property of a control to store the sum of a variable and a counter is a bit weird, why not store this all in a regular variable?)

Comment: This issue got resolved now thank you for your help !!!